# phpMyAdmin: #1064 - SQL syntax when creating a new table

Tags: mysql

I've wanted to build a new table in my database using the phpMyAdmin build-in feature but after I complete all the fields and hit Go - this error occurs:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') NOT NULL, `data` DATETIME NOT NULL , `link_picture` VARCHAR( 250 ) NOT NULL , ' at line 6
```

..and I have no ideea why.

Here's the SQL code:

```
    CREATE TABLE  `prod`.`info_prod` (
 `id` INT( 100 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
 `prod_name` VARCHAR( 250 ) NOT NULL ,
 `link_prod` VARCHAR( 250 ) NOT NULL ,
 `pd` VARCHAR( 10 ) NOT NULL ,
 `price` DOUBLE( 250 ) NOT NULL ,
 `data` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
 `link_picture` VARCHAR( 250 ) NOT NULL ,
 `link_picture2` VARCHAR( 250 ) NOT NULL ,
INDEX (  `pd` ) ,
UNIQUE (
 `prod_name`
)
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

What is the problem with this code?

Comment: The code in the error is not the same code that you've posted.  e.g. where is `link_poza`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like it's just the syntax.

```
 `price` DOUBLE( 250,0 ) NOT NULL
```

[Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fixed-point-types.html)